# Why does this code overflows even when casting?

Tags: c, casting, integer, long-integer

I am studying for an exam that involves C. but I am encountering an error on the variables even when casting them. The code is copied from the powerpoint the professor gave us.

I was going through the Casting section that has this program written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long i;
    int j = 100000;

    i = (long)j * j;
    printf("%li", i);
}
```

I don't know why but that still gives me the output "1410065408" which of course means it's wrong.
I even tried casting both variables:

```
    i = (long)j * (long)j;
    printf("%li", i);
```

I don't know how to move from now on, thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)` on your system?

Comment: `long` is 32 bits wide on your system. You can use `long long` for an integer type that is (at least) 64 bits wide. You will need to use `%lli` to print the `long long` parameter value.

Comment: Pro tip: use `uint64_t`/`int64_t` when you actually need 64 bits and don't want to guess the size of `long` or `int`.

Comment: On my system (Intel 64bit) it prints `10000000000`.  IMHO this is correct.  Probably you have a 32 bit system and `long` is 32 bit (`sizeof(long) == 4`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast only saves the situation in case `long` happens to be 64 bit, which is often not the case.

In case it is 32 bit, then the maximum value of the signed `long` is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 2.147 * 10<sup>9</sup>.
But 100000 * 100000 = 10 * 10<sup>9</sup> so we get an integer overflow no matter the cast.

The solution is to use the portable `int64_t` from `stdint.h` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h> // for printing stdint.h types

int main()
{
    int64_t i;
    int j = 100000;

    i = (int64_t)j * j;
    printf("%" PRIi64, i);
}
```

(It's sufficient to only cast one operator of the `+`, since this means that the smaller operator of lower "conversion rank" gets implicitly promoted to the type of the larger one.)

Comment: Thank you! I fixed and understood the code. But now I'm asking myself. why would my professor write a code which, now I certanly know, overflows?

Comment: Perhaps, @AlessandroSbarsi, because your professor is used to coding for a platform that features 64-bit `long`s?  That would be most of the 64-bit world, with Win64 being a notable exception.  If you really want to know then you'll have to ask them.

Comment: @AlessandroSbarsi Maybe they come from the *nix world, which has 64 bit longs and where it is custom to write non-portable code. The majority of all computer systems in the world use 32 bit longs.

Answer (score 1):

On a system wit 64bit `long` type, the system gives you the correct answer.  In the system you use, the `long` type is 32bit and gives the answer you printed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j = 100000;

    i = (int)j * j;
    printf("%i", i);
}
```

after changing your `long` to `int` on my system (now calculations are done in 32bit) it gives the following answer:

```
$ a.out
1410065408$ _
```

(try to put a `'\n'` at the end of the line, and so you will not get the prompt immediately after the printed number, as in

```
    printf("%i\n", i);
```

You can ssolve your problem, ensuring that you will use a 64bit number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int64_t i;
    int j = 100000;
    i = (int64_t) j * j;
    printf("%lli", (long long) i);
}
```

Be careful because probably your machine lacks a `int128_t` type :)